# Outlook calendar conditional formatting based on customProp/itemClass

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I did not find a way to apply a conditional color formatting to appointments in Outlook Calendar based on customProperties or custom itemClass.

Here's what I did manage to do:

- When I go to Outlook 2016 Conditional Formatting and select the Advanced tab, I can select the `Class` field and set the condition to contains `IPM.Appointment`. When applied this conditional formatting obviously works because all entries are of type `IPM.Appointment` :)
  In the **OfficeJS** documentation it is said: "*You can create custom message classes that extends a default message class, for example, a custom appointment message class IPM.Appointment.Contoso.*" As the `Office.context.mailbox.item.itemClass` property seems readonly, where can I set such a class for my appointment?
- With `loadCustomPropertiesAsync` function, I can load and save custom properties for current item. This option seems pretty cool for what I want to do but I did not find a way to access it through any Outlook 2016 Conditional Formatting fields, any ideas?

These were the 2 things I was thinking of, maybe you have an easiet way to do it in mind?

Answer (score 0):

The itemClass property is only readonly.  The documentation is only pointing out that different appointment types can be created in general, but not through the JS API.

I also cannot find a way to configure conditional formatting fields using custom properties.  One alternative workaround I can think of is to try inserting hidden text that Conditional Formatting fields can look for.  For example, you can use:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.prependAsync(
    '<div style="display:none">some-text-to-look-for-in-view-settings</div>',
    {coercionType:Office.CoercionType.Html},
    function (asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status == "failed") {
           // any error handling
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was thinking of this kind of workaround as well but I was not really happy with that.